# Diagnosis Text Issues With iPhone

Tags: sms, ios

When diagnosis email display issues everything is fairly straight forward because everything is sent as plain text(or HTML+CSS) which allows you to determine the issue.

How can I get the plain text version of text messages being sent from an iPhone.  Right now images are often not coming through to the Android phone when being sent from my iPhone.  I would diagnosis the issue but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Wait, are you sure the number you wish to send messages to isn't also registered on your Apple ID account? If it is, the iPhone might be actually sending iMessages when it can, resulting in some messages being not delivered to an Android phone.

Comment: I meant, is the number of the sim card **in the Android phone** perchance associated to an Apple ID?

Comment: @alex2003super I realized my original comment had a small typo.  Either way I understand what you are asking and the answer is this phone has only been attached to Android devices never an iPhone.